# In moqui-1.6.1, configuration to use mysql and loading data

Tags: mysql, moqui

First just for system configuration status, I have mysql server version 5.5.48 and have latest version of mantle and moqui-framework,
and I am trying to configure moqui to use mysql, I copied the connector to runtime/lib
Then added the following lines for mysql configuration to runtime/conf/MoquiDevConf.xml

```
<entity-facade crypt-pass="MoquiDefaultPassword:123456">
    <!-- add datasource elements here to configure databases -->
    <datasource group-name="transactional" database-conf-name="mysql" schema-name="moqui">
    <inline-jdbc jdbc-uri="jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/moqui?autoReconnect=true&amp;useUnicode=true&amp;characterEncoding=UTF-8"
                 jdbc-username="testUser" jdbc-password="123456" pool-minsize="2" pool-maxsize="50"/>
    </datasource>
</entity-facade>
```

on building and running load, I get this error -

```
Loading entity data from [classpath://entity/BasicEntities.xml]
--- 20:35:44.310 [           main] ERROR           org.moqui.impl.entity.EntityDbMeta
 SQL Exception while executing the following SQL [CREATE TABLE     moqui.ENUMERATION_TYPE (ENUM_TYPE_ID VARCHAR(255) CHARACTER SET utf8     COLLATE utf8_general_ci NOT NULL, DESCRIPTION VARCHAR(255) CHARACTER SET     utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci, LAST_UPDATED_STAMP DATETIME(3), CONSTRAINT     PK_ENUMERATION_TYPE PRIMARY KEY (ENUM_TYPE_ID)) ENGINE InnoDB CHARACTER     SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci]:     com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an     error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL     server version for the right syntax to use near '(3), CONSTRAINT     PK_ENUMERATION_TYPE PRIMARY KEY (ENUM_TYPE_ID)) ENGINE InnoDB CH' at line     1
--- 20:35:44.310 [           main] WARN      moqui.impl.context.TransactionFacadeImpl
 Rollback only not set on current transaction, status is     STATUS_NO_TRANSACTION
--- 20:35:44.310 [           main] INFO            org.moqui.impl.entity.EntityDbMeta
```

-- thanks for any help :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The current MySQL configuration (in MoquiDefaultConf.xml) uses the type DATETIME(3) for date-time columns. This is the setting for the latest MySQL because after a certain version (5.7 IIRC) the DATETIME type no longer has millisecond values by default. Unfortunately versions before this did not support specifying sub-second precision, so there is NO setting that works with both pre-5.7 and post-5.7 versions. Thanks Oracle!

You can either use a newer version of MySQL, or change the Moqui Conf XML file so the type is plain DATETIME instead of DATETIME(3). You can change the MoquiDefaultConf.xml file, or set it using the same elements in your runtime conf XML file (like MoquiDevConf.xml, MoquiProductionConf.xml, etc) along with your datasource settings. The entire XML file gets merged at runtime, so you can override anything in the MoquiDefaultConf.xml file in your runtime conf file.

Comment: Thanks @David for your quick reply :)